# How to test the column index if there are many targets in the columnDefs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

There are many targets defined in a columnDefs :

```
"columnDefs":[
               {
                 "targets":[1,3],
                 "render":function ( data, type, row ) {
                             return '<span class="fa-stack" title="En mouvement"><i class="fa fa-circle rouge fa-stack"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack"></i></span>';
                          }
               }
             ]
```

I want to make a test according to the target value inside of the "render" option. How to test if the `target` is 1 for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback function within `render` option [accepts](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) 4 parameters, where the last one is object of the following format: `{row: rowIndex, col: colIndex}`, where `col` property is essentially column index (i.e. current target column)

So, basically, what you need is:

```
"columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [1, 3],
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
            if(meta.col == 1) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: in fact the parameters should be `function (data, type, row, obj)` and we access the column index like this `obj.col`

Comment: @pheromix: you're right, destructuring doesn't work as expected in that case, for some reason, fixed code sample accordingly.